# How can I find and hire an intern for website-specific photography?

Tags: business, contracts

I've built a fairly high ranking site on Google and am planning to expand it this year.  I would like to have an exclusive photographer, but would like a trial period with someone before I consider a hire (as our tastes may differ, or their photos may not sit well with my readers and clients).  Upon thinking about this, a young photographer looking to build a client list and a reference or two would probably be best, as he/she could intern while I evaluate their work.  For those familiar with the process, a few questions:

1. Where is a good place to find entry-level photographers, trying to gain a client list and references, outside of posting on a college or high school board?
2. How to contracts typically work for photographers?  I'll explain: if I like the photographer's work, I'll want to keep them on board - I'm curious as to how photographers are paid (hourly, per project, etc).

Comment: Are you looking for someone to do the work for free? You will most likely find someone but you are destroying the market for freelance photographers. If you can afford a pro, then pleas do hire one. You will be happier with the results.

Comment: He is looking for an intern. This does not necessarily mean someone who is not paid. Usually they are paid a low fee, in exchange for being more forgiving in quality - usually a good start for young guys in photography. Don't down-vote the question just because of that. They build some experience and can expand their portfolios with this.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about hiring a photographer for a business, not photography

Answer (score -2):

Check out stock libraries like [iStock](http://istockphoto.com), maybe you'll find what you are looking for there.

Comment: He is looking for a photographer, not photos.